# .htaccess language detection, redirect and friendly URLs

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, language, detection

I'm having problems with my *.htaccess* file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/frans [R,L]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/nederlands [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone please help?

I want it to detect the browser language of the client, then redirect French to `/frans`, and all other languages to `/nederlands`.

Also I want to show the URLs without `.html` or `.php` at the end, so clean URLs.

Comment: Please, explain a little bit more what do you exactly want to do.

Comment: I think it is clear now. ty

Comment: Removing file extensions like `.php` can be problematic - see this answer and comments: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52518/clean-urls-without-php-file-extension There are many questions here on how to remove `.html`. You might do better to look at those, and edit your question to be specific to just redirecting based on the language, since it's really too broad otherwise.